# Java Hibernate @SafeHtml not allows url links

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to have XSS filter in my textfield, but i need to allow certain html tags for text formatting (bold, italic, etc), and i also need to allow url links like:

```
<p style='text-align: left;'><a href='google.com'>then with links!</a></p>
```

So in my entity class i added whitelist:

```
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.RELAXED,
        additionalTagsWithAttributes = { 
                @SafeHtml.Tag(name = "a", attributes = { "href" })
})
private String body;
```

But it still gives me the following error:

```
may have unsafe html content
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems one is that `style` attribute is not supported on the `p` tag and second problem is that the `href` attribute is missing the protocol which is required  by all the `WhiteListType`s. See the list below for protocols which are supported by tag and attribute for Relaxed `WhiteListType`

### Relaxed

- tag "a", attribute "href", protocols {"ftp", "http", "https", "mailto"}
- tag "blockquote", attribute "cite", protocols {"http", "https"}
- tag "cite", attribute "cite", protocols {"http", "https"}
- tag "img", attribute "src", protocols {"http", "https"}
- tag "q", attribute "cite", protocols {"http", "https"}

So in you case the text

`<p style='text-align: left;'><a href='google.com'>then with links!</a></p>`

should be changed to

`<p style='text-align: left;'><a href='http://google.com'>then with links!</a></p>`
and no, there is no easy way to add custom protocols :)

And the java code should be changed to

```
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.RELAXED,
    additionalTagsWithAttributes = { 
            @SafeHtml.Tag(name = "p", attributes = { "style" })
})
private String body;
```

Starting from Hibernate Validator 6 you can also provide the custom list of protocols. But sadly the `@SafeHtml` also marked as deprecated, so consider writing your own validator instead.

```
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = SafeHtml.WhiteListType.RELAXED,
    additionalTagsWithAttributes = {
            @SafeHtml.Tag(name = "p",
                    attributes = { "style" },
                    attributesWithProtocols = {
                        @SafeHtml.Attribute(name = "a", protocols = {"http", "https"})
            })
})
private String body;
```

Comment: Version 6.0 of Hibernate Validator that has since been released added the attributesWithProtocols argument to the SafeHtml.Tag. This now allows you to add your own custom protocols: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/SafeHtml.Tag.html#attributesWithProtocols--